# msiexec command not found in linux to install msi file

Tags: linux

I had a `.msi` file which is developed in asp.net in windows now i want to install `.msi` file in linux by using the command in terminal as follows:

```
msiexec /i myfile.msi
```

but it show:

> `msiexec` command not found

Comment: You could try `lessmsi` or `msiexec` through `wine`. Maybe it will work.

Comment: Is this done with "asp.net" or "asp.net core" ?  Big difference.  The .net core stuff will work in Linux as is (just repackage).  Esp v3+.  Otherwise, it *might* work using wine but I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

.msi files are designed specifically for Windows. "msi" is short for **M**icro**s**oft **I**nstaller. You can not properly "install" an .msi file in Linux. You might be able to find some tools that would allow you to look inside of that file. But the nature of that file is it's specifically created to be a Windows executable that utilizes Windows Installer Service. `msiexec` is a Windows command. Typing that in Linux will not work.

You should go back to whoever created that .msi file and request a Linux-native package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `.MSI` file by using `wine` command, for example:

```
wine msiexec /i myfile.msi
```

If you don't have Wine, [install](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_Installation_and_Configuration) it first.